# How to store key-value pairs in a .csv file and then retrieve them as an associative array?

Tags: php, file, csv, associative-array, fgetcsv

When I apply the following piece of code for a `.csv` file containing contents: `WaterMelon,BlueBerry,BlackBerry`, I get the **output:** **`Array ( [0] => WaterMelon, [1]=>BlueBerry, [2]=>BlackBerry )`**

The output I have got is a simple array, because I had stored simple values into the `.csv` file.

**QUESTION:-**

***But what if I want to store `key-value pairs` in a .csv file, and then get the output like:
`Array ( [FruitOne] => WaterMelon, [FruitTwo]=>BlueBerry, [FruitThree]=>BlackBerry )`
How can I do that?***

```
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
  //$line is an array of the csv elements
  print_r($line); //check. print_r() returns an array in human readable form.
}

fclose($file);
```

Comment: is csv the appropriate format for this? what about serialize() on the array

Comment: @Dagon A little reading on serialize() tells me that I can call this function on the array, it will generate a storable version of the array, then can I store this "storable version" in a file? Secondly, the values will be added to the array (or the file, whatever I use) dynamically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A CSV file can and many times does have a header row.  So you could use this to read the first line and then use `array_combine`:

```
$headers = fgetcsv($file);
while (($line = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) {
    print_r(array_combine($headers, $line));
}
```

Use the same concept when creating the CSV file to add the headers.

Alternately, just define `$headers` yourself and use the same loop and `array_combine`:

```
$headers = array('FruitOne', 'FruitTwo', 'FruitThree');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?php 
    function getArrayFromCsv($file) { 
        if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) { 
            while (($lineArray = fgetcsv($handle)) !== FALSE) { 
               $dataArray[$lineArray[0]] = $lineArray[1]; 
            } 
            fclose($handle); 
        } 
        return $dataArray; 
    } 
?>
```